# Incrementing pointer not working

Tags: c++, pointers

I’m trying to increment pointer. I was sure that it is similar to do `i+=1` , but I’m getting adress.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    int *a = &i;
    *a++;
    cout << *a;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain why ?

Comment: You don't get an address, you're getting some indeterminate number that happens to be very large.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`++` has a higher operator precedence than the pointer dereference operator `*`.

So what `*a++` does is to return the value of `i` (the old value of `*a`) before incrementing the *pointer* value.

After that expression has been evaluated, `a` now points to something other than the address of `i`, and the behaviour of a subsequent `*a` is *undefined*.

If you want to increment `i` via the pointer, then use `(*a)++;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want your output to be "43", than you have to change `*a++;` to `(*a)++;`.

But other than for testing and learning, code like yours is more of a "C thing" than a "C++ thing".  C++ offers another approach to referencing data and operating on it, through what the language calls “references”.

```
int i=42;
int &a=i;  // ‘a’ is a reference to ‘i’
a++;
assert(i==43);  // Assertion will not fail
```

References are especially useful for passing arguments to functions, without the risk of having null or displaced pointers.

Answer (score 2):

What does "I'm getting adress" mean?

Have you checked out order of operations?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

++-postfix is a higher precedence than *-dereference - hence:

```
*a++;
```

is really:

```
*(a++);
```

and not:

```
(*a)++;
```

... as you probably meant.  Which is IMHO why I always recommend erring on the side of too many parentheses rather than too few. Be explicit as to what you mean  :)

Comment: Good answer (plus one) although I respectfully disagree with your last statement. To me, inclusion of parentheses signals the intention to deviate from normal operator behaviour. There are plenty of well-respected programmers on this site that take the opposite view though.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `*a++;`

As your increment operator `++` has higher precedence than your pointer `*`, what actually is happening is that your pointer address is being incremented. So the new *a has no defined value and hence it will give an undefined value
`*a++;` is the equivalent of `a++;`

To fix this you can use parentheses `(*a)++;` or simply us pre increment operator `++*a;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine till you reach the line

```
*a++;
```

As you know, C++ compiler will break this code of line as

```
*a = *(a+1);
```

That is, it will first increment address value of **a** and then assign the value to ***a**. But if you do,

```
*(a)++;
```

then you will get correct output, that is, 43.

For output- http://ideone.com/QFBjTZ